# Ошибка при переименовании директории

Tags: php

Добрый день. Помогите пожалуйста. Почему при переименовании директории через функцию rename() в последней строчке кода происходит ошибка?

```
$first_file_name = "test.txt";
$second_file_name = "mir.txt";
$first_folder = "folder";
$second_folder = "test";
$third_folder = "www";
$copy_file_name = "world.txt";

file_put_contents($first_file_name, "Hello, world");
echo file_get_contents($first_file_name)."<br>";
rename($first_file_name, $second_file_name);
if (!file_exists($first_folder))
    if (!mkdir($first_folder))
        echo "Error while creating folder <br>";

$handle = fopen($first_folder."/".$first_file_name, 'w');

if (!copy($second_file_name, $copy_file_name)) 
    echo "Error while coping file <br>";

$size_of_file = filesize($copy_file_name);
echo "Size of file : <br>".$size_of_file." bytes<br>".$size_of_file/pow(2, 20)." megabytes                    <br>".$size_of_file/pow(2, 30)." gigabytes<br>";

if (!unlink($copy_file_name))
    echo "Error while removing file <br>";

if (!file_exists($second_folder))
    if (!mkdir($second_folder))
        echo "Error while creating folder <br>";    

rename($second_folder, $third_folder);
```

[скрин ошибки](https://mega.nz/#!42BwhB6Z!4-2wCDPomiCSAfu3TxD5zRrf2InG57CPexn6KUh7Qvg)

Comment: а какая ошибка?

Comment: может потому что `$third_folder` уже существует? чего гадать, кодировку в браузере смените, и прочитайте что за текст ошибки скрывается за этими ромбиками

Comment: Andrey покажи ошибку, не мучай народ ))

Comment: Спасибо всем. Уже разобрался, ошибка была в том, что папка www уже существовала (не понятно, почему она создалась после запуска кода в первый раз, еще раз запустил код после ее удаления, больше такого не было), соответственно двух папок с одинаковыми именами быть не должно, поэтому переименовать не удалось.

Comment: @AndreyRafalsky если разобрались и проблемы больше нет, то возможно стоит удалить вопрос как ненужный.